# Does Spring close connection after committing transaction?

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I've recently read in one tutorial that Spring closes connection after transaction commit.

Is that true? I can't find anything about it in the Spring reference documentation.

What's the rationale behind it? Since now, I thought that there is a one-to-many relation between connection and transactions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring calls `close()` when the transaction finishes which could be from either a commit or rollback. Whether or not `close()` actually closes a real JDBC connection depends on the `DataSource` configuration. If it's a plain JDBC connection, then it will actually close. If it is a connection pool then it will probably just be returned to the pool on close.

Comment: Thanks for response, could you please point me to spring class that is closing connection?

Comment: Look at `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection()`. This is called by `DataSourceTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion()` as well as the TransactionSyncronization handlers.

Comment: How does Spring determine if DataSource is a connection pool?

Comment: @user64141: It does not: A Pool typically creates a DataSource, where any Connections returned are wrapped - and this wrapper overrides .close() to instead of actually closing the underlying (wrapped) connection, returns the Connection to the pool.

Answer (score 0):

No, the connection is closed only when `SessionFactory` bean is destroyed.