# Transcations level scope in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4 and trying to understand how does Spring Transaction Management works.

Here is my question:

Lets say I have a service with a method `A` that is annotated with `@Transactional(isolation = SERIALIZABLE)` and another method `B` annotated with `@Transactional(isolation = READ_COMMITED)`.

And then let's imagine that some service `X` calls these two methods `A` and `B` sequentially. 
My colleague says that transaction level is set per connection in `Spring`. Which means that if the same connection from the pool is used for these two sequential calls, then isolation level for both transactions `A` and `B` = SERIALIZABLE.

However, to me it seems a bit strange. I would expect that these two transactions would have different level of isolations, because all sql databases allow to set isolation level for a given transaction explicitly.

I was trying to read documentation and couldn't find a place where it would be mentioned that transcation level is assigned to connection.

Can someone judge us on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no transaction started when calling method A() or B() a new transaction is created when calling the method and gets closed when leaving the method. The used connection returns to pool or gets closed.
This thread explains what happens to the connection when transaction gets closed:
[Does Spring close connection after committing transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205556/does-spring-close-connection-after-committing-transaction)

In case there exists a transaction that wraps both methods, there is only one connection used for both methods; and i guess the isolation level is the one defined by the bigger transaction.